# Next.js App router i18n '/' for default language

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, i18next

I am migrating from Next.js **/pages** to **/app** and I have 2 languages **en** and **es**, the default language is **en** and the url structure is:

English

- example.com/
- example.com/blog/my-post

Spanish

- example.com/es
- example.com/es/blog/mi-articulo

But when integrating i18n on app router I created a **[lang]** folder, and after following any of these guides:

https://locize.com/blog/next-13-app-dir-i18n/

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization

My structure on /app/[lang] is:

English

- example.com/en
- example.com/en/blog/my-post

Spanish

- example.com/es
- example.com/es/blog/mi-articulo

If I go to **example.com/** I will be redirected to **example.com/en**, if I don't solve this I will have problem with our current SEO because the majority of URLs will change.

Comment: same here. any solutions so far?

Comment: same here! Still looking for a solution to this.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I've referred to examples for localizing the app directory in Next.js v14 from sources such as https://locize.com/blog/next-app-dir-i18n/ and https://carlogino.com/blog/nextjs13-i18n, but unfortunately, I'm still encountering issues with implementation.

Comment: Please let me know if you discover a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [rewrite api](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites) of NextResponse.

So in the [document of nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization), the return value of the middleware is a `Response.redirect(request.nextUrl)` which redirect the client to the url contains locale information.

Replace it with `NextResponse.rewrite(request.nextUrl)`, the new url will be accepted to server internally only, without affecting client side. Kind of like a 'proxy' in some way.

* NextResponse can be imported from next/server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have this structure :

English

- example.com/
- example.com/blog/my-post

Spanish

- example.com/es
- example.com/es/blog/mi-articulo

**2 options :**

1. use [rewrite api](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites) yourself
2. use [next-international](https://github.com/QuiiBz/next-international) who do it for you

see [docs](https://next-international.vercel.app/docs/app-middleware-configuration)

see the example [here](https://github.com/QuiiBz/next-international/tree/main/examples/next-app)

and configure the middleware like this :

**urlMappingStrategy: 'rewriteDefault',**

```
import { createI18nMiddleware } from 'next-international/middleware';
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

const I18nMiddleware = createI18nMiddleware({
  locales: ['en', 'es'],
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  urlMappingStrategy: 'rewriteDefault',
});

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return I18nMiddleware(request);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next|favicon.ico|robots.txt).*)'],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best and simple usage I found
Doc - [next-intl](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router)

Update the middle ware configuration like this.

```
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware'

export default createMiddleware({
  locales: ['en', 'ja'],
  defaultLocale: 'ja',
  localePrefix: 'as-needed',
})

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)'],
}
```